# Postfix Plugins for Munin not working

Tags: postfix, munin

I have a fresh munin (system monitor) installation on a FreeBSD 9.1 machine up and
running fine. Now I wanted to include our Postfix server on the same
machine in munin, so I tried to run the standard "postfix_mailqueue" plugin
with the "autoconf" parameter. However, this does not seem to work
because "plugin.sh" is not found.

Here is some output from command line:

```
root@chaos ~ % echo $MUNIN_LIBDIR
/usr/local/share/munin
root@chaos ~ %
root@chaos ~ % file $MUNIN_LIBDIR/plugins/plugin.sh
/usr/local/share/munin/plugins/plugin.sh: ASCII text
root@chaos ~ %
root@chaos ~ % /usr/local/share/munin/plugins/postfix_mailqueue autoconf
.: cannot open /plugins/plugin.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

PS: Other standard munin plugins are working fine, e.g. for Apache.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `postfix_mailqueue` plugin is not getting the `$MUNIN_LIBDIR` environment variable.  Since it's set in your shell, you probably just need to export it.  It looks like you're running (t)csh, so you should use `setenv MUNIN_LIBDIR /usr/local/share/munin`.  If you're running a bourne shell derivative, the command is `export MUNIN_LIBDIR=/usr/local/share/munin`.

Alternately, you can run the plugin via `munin-run`, which sets up all of the right environment variables for you.  To run it directly from the main plugin directory, use `munin-run --servicedir /usr/local/share/munin/plugins/ postfix_mailqueue autoconf`.